# Firebird TIBQuery insert with returning ... INTO

Tags: delphi, firebird, c++builder

I have a firebird 2.x database with Generator and a trigger to generate the key field.
I need to get the returned value from below query.

```
INSERT INTO XXXX (vdate,description) values ('"+ VDate +"','"+ Description +"') returning vno INTO :ParamVoucherNo
```

I tried several versions of below code but it dont wrok and I get

> Dynamic sql error sql error code = -104

Is it really possible to get the return value in delphi using TIBQuery ?

```
Query1->SQL->Clear();
Query1->SQL->Add("INSERT INTO XXXX (vodate,description) values ('"+ VDate +"','"+ Description +"') returning vno INTO :ParamVoucherNo");

Query1->Params->ParamByName("ParamVoucherno")->ParamType = ptResult;
Query1->Params->ParamByName("ParamVoucherno")->DataType = ftInteger;
Query1->Params->ParamByName("ParamVoucherno")->Value = "";
Query1->Prepare();
Query1->ExecSQL();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm rusty on the TADO, but I believe you do have the option to get a return value from the insert (I assume auto-increment) from the database. There should be an option on the TADOQuery or the TADOConnection objects to return the value of an auto-increment. I'm not up to speed on firebird, but this does require the driver implement the option. Your other option is following it up with a SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Table, but that leads to concurrency errors and should be avoided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Firebird README.returning:

> The INTO part (i.e. the variable list) is allowed in PSQL only (to
>   assign local variables) and rejected in DSQL.

As IBX uses DSQL, you should exclude `INTO` part from your query.

`INSERT ... RETURNING` for DSQL looks the same as a call of a stored procedure, which returns result set. So, you have to use `Open` instead of `ExecSQL`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However i already tried that. And if i use Open() then i dont get DSQL Error, But the resulting dataset is just empty. (i.e Query1->RecordCount == 0) so i cant get the retruned value

Comment: I am not experienced with IBX, but probably it does not support RETURNING clause. That works with AnyDAC, which i am using.

Answer (score 3):

Your mixing of dynamic SQL with parameters is just confusing.

Do this instead:

```
Query1->SQL->Clear();
Query1->SQL->Add("INSERT INTO table1 (vodate,description) VALUES"+
                 "(:VoDate,:Description) RETURNING vno INTO :VoucherNo ");
Query1->Params->ParamByName("VoDate")->Value = VDate;
Query1->Params->ParamByName("description")->Value = Description;

Query1->Prepare();
Query1->ExecSQL();
VoucherNo = Query1->Params->ParamByName("VoucherNo")->AsInteger;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried that already , and it raise same error i mentioned in my first post

Answer (score 2):

Using Delphi 6 I have the ID returning successfully using an EXECUTE BLOCK statement:

```
EXECUTE BLOCK
RETURNS ( DeptKey INT )
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT 
      ( COMPANY_KEY, DEPARTMENT_NAME ) 
      VALUES ( 1, 'TEST1' ) RETURNING DEPARTMENT_KEY INTO :DeptKey;
  SUSPEND;
END;
```

From Delphi you can do the folliowing:

```
FQuery.SQL.Text := '<Execute Block Statement>';
FQuery.Open();
ANewKey := FQuery.Fields[0].AsInteger;
```

Answer (score 1):

IBX is not Firebird ready

you can take a look at [FIBPLUS](http://www.devrace.com) who support Firebird features

> FIBPlus also supports FB2.0 insert ... into ... returning. Now you
>   should not bother about getting generator values from the client but
>   leave them in the trigger. You can also use RDB$DB_KEY. New possible
>   variants of work with insert returning and RDB$DB_KEY are shown in the
>   example “FB2InsertReturning”.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if that `INSERT` can be wrapped into `EXECUTE BLOCK` command.
Would IBX manage `EXECUTE BLOCK` then?

- https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref25/fblangref25-dml-execblock.html
- https://firebirdsql.su/doku.php?id=execute_block

*Hope to try it in both IBX and Unified Interbase in XE2*

PS: Even if it does not, I found the library, that tells to work on top of IBX of Delphi XE2 (both x86 and x64) and to add `EXECUTE BLOCK` support: http://www.loginovprojects.ru/index.php?page=ibxfbutils#eb.

Answer (score 0):

Why not get the next value for VoucherNo first, followed by

```
"INSERT INTO table1 (vno, vodate,description) VALUES (:VoucherNo,:VoDate,:Description)");
```

?

Your trigger can then either be dispensed with (which is nice), or modified to detect null (or <= zero can be useful too) and only then populate the vno field.

```
create trigger bi_mytable
  active before insert position 1
  on mytable
as
begin
  if (new.vno is null)
    then new.vno = next value for gen_VoucherNos;
end
```

Client-side you can :

```
select gen_id(gen_VoucherNos, 1) from rdb$database;
```

By modifying the trigger in this manner you save yourself a headache later on if/when you want to insert blocks of records

Comment: The whole idea about INSERT ... RETURNING is that you don't need to get that value first, but let the trigger generate it, and then return that value.

Comment: @HughJones: I see it as an perfectly acceptable workaround the issue of IBX not capable of dealing with INSERT..RETURNING (which, by the way, is a very convenient syntax). Upvoted.

Comment: @Hugh Jones: It saves several roundtrips to the database, so it should perform slightly better, secondly it saves coding in handling the retrieval of the generator value before the insert.

Answer (score 0):

As I know there should be some changes to IBX made. Internally `INSERT ... RETURNING` should be treated the same way as a selectable procedure with returning parameters.

Answer (score 0):

i know this question was answered a long time ago, but i must write this as clear as possible, for those who need this as i was.

i too, needed the "INSERT..RETURNING" thing.
the Delphi drove me crazy for a long time, until i changed my Data access components.
i even moved from Delphi XE2, to XE5 only because of that...

conclusion : IBX does NOT support RETURNING!
FireDAC is PERFECT for what i need with Firebird.

just move to FireDAC and you'll be able to do everything you need, and with high performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table with this 2 Fields: GRP_NO and GROUPNAME and you want to get the new GRP_NO you have to use **RET_** as prefix, see example:

```
procedure TFormDatenbank.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  q: Uni.TUniQuery;
  ID: Integer;
  GroupName: String;
begin
  GroupName := 'MyGroupName';

  q := TUniQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    q.Connection := Datenmodul.UniConnection;
    q.ParamCheck := true; // the default value of ParamCheck is true.
    q.SQL.Clear;
    q.SQL.Add('SELECT GRP_NO, GROUPNAME FROM GROUPDATA WHERE GROUPNAME = :GROUPNAME');
    q.ParamByName('GROUPNAME').AsString := GroupName;
    q.Open;

    if q.RecordCount > 0 then
      ID := q.FieldByName('GRP_NO').AsInteger
    else
    begin
      // there exist no group with this name, so insert this new name
      q.SQL.Clear;
      q.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO GROUPDATA');
      q.SQL.Add('(GROUPNAME)');
      q.SQL.Add('VALUES');
      q.SQL.Add('(:GROUPNAME)');
      q.SQL.Add('RETURNING GRP_NO;');

      q.ParamByName('GROUPNAME').AsString := GroupName;
      q.Execute;
      ID := q.ParamByName('RET_GRP_NO').AsInteger;
    end;
  finally
    q.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the IBx2 sources, you can do it like this:

```
//Uses IBSql;
//var   Cur: IResults;
  IBSQL1.SQL.Text := 'delete from tbl_document where id = 120 returning id;';
  IBSQL1.Prepare;
  if IBSQL1.Prepared then
  begin
    Cur := IBSQL1.Statement.Execute(IBTransaction1.TransactionIntf);
    WriteLn(Cur.Data[cou].AsString);
    Cur.GetTransaction.Commit(True);
  end;
```

IResults interface Code:

```
  IResults = interface
   function getCount: integer;
   function GetTransaction: ITransaction;
   function ByName(Idx: String): ISQLData;
   function getSQLData(index: integer): ISQLData;
   procedure GetData(index: integer; var IsNull:boolean; var len: short; var data: PChar);
   procedure SetRetainInterfaces(aValue: boolean);
   property Data[index: integer]: ISQLData read getSQLData; default;
   property Count: integer read getCount;
  end;
```

Test enviroment:
   Arch Linux X86
   Firebird 3
   Lazarus 1.9
   FPC 3.0.4 
Quick note: This works on new Firebird API in the IBX, But I didn't test it in Legacy Firebird API with the IBX.